# how to get wifi to work on fujitsu siemens v2000

Tags: windows-xp, wifi-driver

I got my mother an old fujitsu siemens v2000 to use, but I can not see any wifi connections.

- According to the device manager, the driver is installed. It is listed as Intel Pro/wireless LAN 2100 3B Mini PCI adapter. Update Driver does not help.
- Ipconfig /all lists the mac address, but the state is disconnected.
- If I try to list the connections, I get: "No wireless networks were found in range"
- Disabling the wireless security on the router does not help. So even open networks are invisible for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the wireless switch enabled? The manufacturer's site provides some instructions for Windows XP: http://uk.ts.fujitsu.com/rl/servicesupport/techsupport/lifebook/General/AmiloWLAN.htm (apparently some proprietary utility must be running to enable radio).

Comment: It was not enabled, and the driver for the button was not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the hardware is ok? You can check it running a Linux Distro. I'd suggest to download a live DVD of [Linux Mint 14 xfce edition](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=127)  to check that out.

After downloading the ISO it's not necessary to burn it on a DVD, you can use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net)  to 'burn' it onto a bootable USB stick.

Comment: Edited the original question

Comment: Using linux helped to find out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To check if you're running the latest drivers, connect to the internet using a cable and use Internet Explorer to serve the [Online Driver Utility page from Intel](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect?iid=dc_iduu). Intel will suggest newer drivers if applicable.

Comment: Please note that you can [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/591476/edit) your answers to add more information.